# Window placement issue - what is re-positioning my window?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a C++ / MFC app and I trying to save and restore the window placement of my CFrameWnd derived main frame. I have my **GetWindowPlacement** and **SetWindowPlacement** calls in the appropriate places, and all seems to be working well.

That is until I 'store' the window when it is maximised. In that case, when I re-open the app and use the debugger to step over my **SetWindowPlacement** call, I see that it is placed maximised, as I wanted.

But then if I continue execution, something else 'restores' my window to it's non-maximised size. How do I discover what is doing that? (Since I'm not calling ShowWindow anywhere else)

**EDIT:** It seems to stem from **CFrameWnd::InitialUpdateFrame**:

```
    int nCmdShow = -1;      // default
    CWinApp* pApp = AfxGetApp();
    if (pApp != NULL && pApp->m_pMainWnd == this)
    {
        nCmdShow = pApp->m_nCmdShow; // use the parameter from WinMain
        pApp->m_nCmdShow = -1; // set to default after first time
    }
    ActivateFrame(nCmdShow);
```

If I set my app m_nCmdShow to SW_MAXIMIZED on start up, it shows maxed - but it's always maxed! I have my **SetWindowPlacement** in my **CMainFrame::OnActivate** - should it be somewhere else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So In my App start up I did this:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT* lwp;
UINT nl;
if (AfxGetApp()->GetProfileBinary(_T("MainFrame"), _T("WP"), (LPBYTE*)&lwp, &nl))
{
    m_nCmdShow = lwp->showCmd;
}
delete [] lwp;
```

It seems to work

Comment: @bar: [CWinApp::GetProfileBinary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class#getprofilebinary) does indeed allocate the buffer for you. While the code here follows the instructions, it's still wrong. `lwp` needs to be of type `LPBYTE`, otherwise the `delete [] lwp;` statement does the wrong thing. As written, the behavior is undefined.